# How to calculate x an y coordinates of svg text from an div to svg element using jquery or javascript?

Tags: php, jquery, svg

I am using custom designer tool which will have multiple svg element. I need to calculate x and y axis from div element to svg tag how to achieve this. please guide me to resolvet this.

For example:

```
    <div class="design-area" style="height: 500px; width: 500px; left: 0px; top: 52%; border-radius: 0px; margin: 0px auto; right: 0px; transform: translateY(-50%); overflow: visible;">
        <svg width="219" height="109" viewBox="0 0 219 109">
<text>adsfasdf
</text></svg>
     <svg width="219" height="109" viewBox="0 0 219 109">
<text>adsfasdf
</text></svg>
        </div>
```

Comment: have you search internet?!!

Comment: No my question is differenet i need to calculate x and y position of the text from div element to svg text element.

Comment: y is distance from top of parent element.

Comment: and there is so much solutions for x, distance from left!

Comment: actualy i am getting top,left,width,height from these how to calculate x and y axis position

Comment: you can find all from internet! just do some searches!